# Python: scatter plot with non-linear x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I have data with lots of x values around zero and only a few as you go up to around 950,

[image: linear scatter point of data]

I want to create a plot with a non-linear x axis so that the relationship can be seen in a 'straight line' form. Like seen in this example,

[image: non-linear scale example]

I have tried using `plt.xscale('log')` but it does not achieve what I want.

I have not been able to use the log scale function with a scatter plot as it then only shows 3 values rather than the thousands that exist.

[image: plt.scatter with log scale]

I have tried to work around it using

```
plt.plot(retper, aep_NW[y], marker='o', linewidth=0)
```

to replicate the scatter function which plots but does not show what I want.

[image: plt.plot graph with log scale]

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(rp,aep,label="SSI sum")
plt.show()
```

Image 3:

```
plt.figure(3)
plt.scatter(rp, aep)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Image 4:

```
plt.figure(4)
plt.plot(rp, aep, marker='o', linewidth=0)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

ADDITION:
Hi thank you for the response.
I think you are right that my x axis is truncated but I'm not sure why or how...
I'm not really sure what to post code wise as the data is all large and coming from a server so can't really give you the data to see it with.

Basically aep_NW is a one dimensional array with 951 elements, values from 0-~140, with most values being small and only a few larger values. The data represents a storm severity index for 951 years.

Then I want the x axis to be the return period for these values, so basically I made a rp array, of the same size, which is given values from 951 down decreasing my a half each time.

I then sort the aep_NW values from lowest to highest with the highest value being associated with the largest return value (951), then the second highest aep_NW value associated with the second largest return period value (475.5) ect.

So then when I plot it I need the x axis scale to be similar to the example you showed above or the first image I attatched originally.

```
rp = [0]*numseas.shape[0]
i = numseas.shape[0] - 1
rp[i] = numseas.shape[0]
i = i - 1
while i != 0:
    rp[i] = rp[i+1]/2
    i = i - 1

y = np.argsort(aep_NW)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(rp,aep_NW[y],label="SSI sum")
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel("Return period")
ax.set_ylabel("SSI score")
plt.title("AEP for NW Europe: total loss per entire extended winter season")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your "[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68thx.png)" the x axis is truncated, so that you don't see the data you are interested in.  It appears this is due to there being 0's in your 'rp' array.  I updated the examples to show the error you are seeing, one way to exclude the zeros, and one way to clip them and show them on a different scale.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

n = 100
numseas = np.logspace(-5, 3, n)
aep_NW = np.linspace(0, 140, n)

rp = [0]*numseas.shape[0]
i = numseas.shape[0] - 1
rp[i] = numseas.shape[0]
i = i - 1
while i != 0:
    rp[i] = rp[i+1] /2
    i = i - 1

y = np.argsort(aep_NW)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(14, 5))
ax = axes[0]
ax.scatter(rp, aep_NW[y], label="SSI sum")
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel("Return period")
ax.set_ylabel("SSI score")

ax = axes[1]
rp = np.array(rp)[y]
mask = rp > 0
ax.scatter(rp[mask], aep_NW[y][mask], label="SSI sum")
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel("Return period (0 values excluded)")

ax = axes[2]
log2_clipped_rp = np.log2(rp.clip(2**-100, None))[y]
ax.scatter(log2_clipped_rp, aep_NW[y], label="SSI sum")
xticks = list(range(-110, 11, 20))
xticklabels = [f'$2^{{{i}}}$' for i in xticks]
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)
ax.set_xlabel("log$_2$ Return period (values clipped to 2$^{-100}$)")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response :) I have tried to give some more details above

Comment: I added some edits that will hopefully help - it seems there may be zeros in your data that are throwing off the log scale.